# Headless Quick Action Not Working As Expected

Tags: lightning-web-components, xml, headless-lwc

I have an aura component being used as a wrapper around a LWC that is in a lightning action on the highlights panel of the lightning page. When I attempt to create the LWC as a "lightning_recordAction" to create the headless quick action, the modal/ screen still pops when I click on the button. Can anyone tell me if there is something known with aura and LWC that would be blocking the headless action from working properly? My HTML is a blank  and the below is my LWC xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
   <targets>
       <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
   </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
   <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
     <actionType>Action</actionType>
   </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in wrapping the LWC with an Aura component.

If you're wanting a headless action, you need to ensure that the LWC is what is being called by your action not an Aura component. By wrapping this in an aura component, you're not actually using the headless capability and the quick action will be rendering the Aura component and hence popping up the modal.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. Is there a way to have an aura component be headless? I have a button on an Quote that needs a LWC to run as a headless action.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. If you have the LWC already, is there a reason you need the Aura component at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, SF doesn't allow for LWC on custom buttons on Quote object. So I have to wrap it in an aura component or VFP

Comment: Is that still the case? I've just managed to do it in my developer org.

Comment: As far as I can tell it is, the documentation (unless I am missing something more updated) says so and when I attempt to build out a custom button on Quote directly calling the LWC the headless quickaction does nothing. I am using a Unlimited Edition org.

Comment: Do you have a link to that documentation?